# Problem with dependency installation in haskell (cabal)

Tags: haskell

I tried to run a cabal program. So i entered the command `cabal run`. But I get always this error:

```
Failed to build fsnotify-0.4.0.1.
Build log ( C:\Users\Kim
Miller\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\ghc-8.8.4\fsnotify-0.4.0.1-fc6cc60833ed8dae1f18edcf54165185955b17cc.log
):
Preprocessing library for fsnotify-0.4.0.1..
Building library for fsnotify-0.4.0.1..
[ 1 of 10] Compiling System.FSNotify.Find ( src\System\FSNotify\Find.hs, dist\build\System\FSNotify\Find.o )
[ 2 of 10] Compiling System.FSNotify.Path ( src\System\FSNotify\Path.hs, dist\build\System\FSNotify\Path.o )
[ 3 of 10] Compiling System.FSNotify.Types ( src\System\FSNotify\Types.hs, dist\build\System\FSNotify\Types.o )
[ 4 of 10] Compiling System.FSNotify.Listener ( src\System\FSNotify\Listener.hs, dist\build\System\FSNotify\Listener.o )
[ 5 of 10] Compiling System.FSNotify.Polling ( src\System\FSNotify\Polling.hs, dist\build\System\FSNotify\Polling.o )
[ 6 of 10] Compiling System.FSNotify  ( src\System\FSNotify.hs, dist\build\System\FSNotify.o )

src\System\FSNotify.hs:169:34: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class `NativeManager'
    |
169 |     createManager :: Either Text NativeManager -> IO WatchManager
    |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: cabal.exe: Failed to build fsnotify-0.4.0.1 (which is required by
exe:recdiagrams from recdiagrams-0.1.0.0). See the build log above for
details.
```

In the log file the following is written:

```
Preprocessing library for fsnotify-0.4.0.1..
Building library for fsnotify-0.4.0.1..
[ 1 of 10] Compiling System.FSNotify.Find ( src\System\FSNotify\Find.hs, dist\build\System\FSNotify\Find.o )
[ 2 of 10] Compiling System.FSNotify.Path ( src\System\FSNotify\Path.hs, dist\build\System\FSNotify\Path.o )
[ 3 of 10] Compiling System.FSNotify.Types ( src\System\FSNotify\Types.hs, dist\build\System\FSNotify\Types.o )
[ 4 of 10] Compiling System.FSNotify.Listener ( src\System\FSNotify\Listener.hs, dist\build\System\FSNotify\Listener.o )
[ 5 of 10] Compiling System.FSNotify.Polling ( src\System\FSNotify\Polling.hs, dist\build\System\FSNotify\Polling.o )
[ 6 of 10] Compiling System.FSNotify  ( src\System\FSNotify.hs, dist\build\System\FSNotify.o )

src\System\FSNotify.hs:169:34: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class `NativeManager'
    |
169 |     createManager :: Either Text NativeManager -> IO WatchManager
    |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Does somebody know the error or even the solution to fix that one?

Answer (score 3):

This issue is tracked on GitHub: https://github.com/haskell-fswatch/hfsnotify/issues/107. You can try rolling back to an earlier version like 0.4.0.0 or using the version from the current master branch or just wait for a new release.